# 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ud64d'

Tags: python

I have written a python code to read from a log file and save some of the infos from that log file to a text file

This is the log.txt file

```
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: channels=1, size=82434
2022-10-12 18:15:22.992 0026/? I/AsrDecActor25: waiting asr-core ready: 12 secs
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state: START, true
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: asr state 2: START
2022-10-12 18:15:23.058 0199/? I/AsrDecActor27: end of decoding 57 true 0
NEC Input :secure folder app close it
NEC Replacement suggestion :Secure folder
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
Changes : 1
2022-10-12 18:15:23.060 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [NEC] Run completed, Time: 2 ms
PostProcessSubstitutions::Output of question mark processing: secure folder uninstall Kare
[eITN] Input:Secure folder uninstall kare OutputSecure folder uninstall Kare
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR [Timestamp] getTimestamp starts
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR string2IntegerList 14 20 23 32 36 
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR levenshteinMapping
2022-10-12 18:15:23.069 0199/? I/LangPackActor: eASR new ASRResult
2022-10-12 18:15:23.091 0021/? I/AsrDecActor26: decoding
```

Now I have written a code to extract the lines with beginning "NEC Input Before Replace", "NEC Matching Word", "Replaced Word" and "NEC Output After Replace" such that my output.txt file looks like this

```
NEC Input Before Replace : secure folder app close it
NEC Matching Word : secure folder app
Replaced Word  : Secure folder
NEC Output After Replace : Secure folder close it
```

The code I have written for the same is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
f = open('log.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():
    if 'NEC Input Before Replace' or 'NEC Matching Word' or 'Replaced Word' or 'NEC Output After Replace' in line:
        f1.write(line)

    
f1.close()
f.close()
```

But this code is throwing me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 7>()
      7 for line in f.readlines():
      8     if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line or 'NEC Matching Word'  or 'NEC Output After Replace' in line:
----> 9         f1.write(line)
     14 f1.close()
     15 f.close()

File D:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py:19, in IncrementalEncoder.encode(self, input, final)
     18 def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ud64d' in position 20: character maps to <undefined>
```

But when I remove `'Replaced Word'` and `'NEC Output After Replace'` from the condition statement `if 'NEC Input Before Replace' in line or 'NEC Matching Word' or 'Replaced Word' or 'NEC Output After Replace' in line:`, then the code works fine.

Anyone knows what is the issue and how it fix this?

Comment: When you don't specify an encoding for the file you write to, Python chooses your system default encoding. On Windows, this usually sucks. `cp1252` cannot represent most Unicode characters.

Comment: If I add encoding this is just printing the entire log.txt file in my output file

Comment: I have changed the code like this `f1 = open('output.txt', "w", encoding='utf-8')`, which just prints the entire log.txt file in my output

Comment: That's a separate FAQ. I'll add a second duplicate.